# Docker using huge amount of swap memory on Ubuntu 15.04, why?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, docker, swap, ubuntu-15.04

I am suffering from excessive memory usage, currently amounting to ~940 MB physical and ~1 GB swap memory, on my Ubuntu 15.04 x64 Docker (1.9.1-cs2, build 4ade326) host. According to `top`, Docker is responsible for the consumption of about 780 MB of swap memory. How can I figure out why Docker is using so much swap?

I am mainly running a Node.js Docker container, which doesn't seem to consume that much memory. The memory usage is also rising over a few hours, as it's quite modest after booting up.

Comment: Why the vote to close?

Comment: I've enabled memory/swap accounting on the node now, hoping this will reign the swap usage in.

Comment: What do you mean by "According to `top`, Docker is responsible for the consumption of about 780 MB of swap memory"? I suspect you have misread the output.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was reading top's `swap` column for the docker process, quite simply.

Comment: OK, so what appeared in the column?

Comment: @MichaelHampton As I recall, 798720 or so (780 MB in KiB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a super satisfying answer, but [enabling memory and swap accounting](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/#adjust-memory-and-swap-accounting) in the kernel seems to have reined in the excessive memory usage.

Comment: Unfortunately, I see Docker is back to using ~780 MB of swap :( It is the `docker` process itself (according to /proc/<pid>/status) that is responsible for this.